# Impersonation with different machine's account (remote user)

Tags: c#-4.0, impersonation

Is it possible to logon to different machine's account with impersonation? I have to access the folder and read its contents temporarily. After reading process program will revert back to old account which has no access to that folder. I am able to impersonate with different account under same domain and it works. However, I have to update my code for accessing to different machine. I want to modify this code:

```
public WindowsImpersonationContext ImpersonateUser(string sUsername, string sDomain, string sPassword)
        {
            // initialize tokens
            IntPtr pExistingTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
            IntPtr pDuplicateTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
            pExistingTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            pDuplicateTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            // if domain name was blank, assume local machine
            if (sDomain == "")
                sDomain = System.Environment.MachineName;

            try
            {
                string sResult = null;

                const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

                // create token
                const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
                //const int SecurityImpersonation = 2;

                // get handle to token
                bool bImpersonated = LogonUser(sUsername, sDomain, sPassword,
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref pExistingTokenHandle);

                // did impersonation fail?
                if (false == bImpersonated)
                {
                    int nErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    sResult = "Error while logging. Error Code: " + nErrorCode + "\r\n";

                    // show the reason why LogonUser failed
                    MessageBox.Show(this, sResult, "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return null;
                }

                // Get identity before impersonation
                sResult += "Before impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "\r\n";

                bool bRetVal = DuplicateToken(pExistingTokenHandle, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, ref pDuplicateTokenHandle);

                // did DuplicateToken fail?
                if (false == bRetVal)
                {
                    int nErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle); // close existing handle
                    sResult += "DuplicateToken() failed with error code: " + nErrorCode + "\r\n";

                    // show the reason why DuplicateToken failed
                    MessageBox.Show(this, sResult, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // create new identity using new primary token
                    WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(pDuplicateTokenHandle);
                    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

                    // check the identity after impersonation
                    sResult += "After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "\r\n";

                    MessageBox.Show(this, sResult, "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return impersonatedUser;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                // close handle(s)
                if (pExistingTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle);
                if (pDuplicateTokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    CloseHandle(pDuplicateTokenHandle);
            }
        }
```